# Visa was refused because I couldn't demonstrate that I am visiting my mother, can I reapply and what should I change?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

[image: Refusal of visit visa 1]

[image: Refusal of visit visa 2]

What else can be done?

Now that my mother has passed away, can we apply to attend the funeral?

Answer (score 8):

This seems reasonably straightforward to fix, provided that you can supply the evidence requested.

> - your personal circumstances change significantly between now and your next application

Your mother has now passed; this is a significant change in circumstances because the reason for your trip no longer includes the provision of care to your mother. If you can supply a copy of your mother's death certificate that would probably be helpful in supporting the new reason for your trip.

> - you provide compelling new evidence with your next application

As the refusal letter states, you would need to supply at least the following new evidence:

- Your birth certificate which confirms your mother's identity
- Confirmation of employment from your employer
- Bank statements showing your regular cash salary deposits

If you can also supply further evidence of you having seen your mother in the last 15 years (for example, relevant passport stamps or evidence of past travel arrangements), that would probably be helpful in supporting your application.

Comment: +1, you can add something about the details for the funeral arrangements so as to confirm that a funeral is indeed taking place, but it's optional :)